# iterate matches in unnamed groups

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-4.0

given a simple RegEx like so: `^(\d+\D+\d+)(.*)` and a string to parse as `15-APR-2012 @ 11:00:00` using a replace of `[$1]$2` yields `[15-APR-2012] @ 11:00:00` as expected.

My issue is when calling Regex.Matches on this I receive one match at index 0 and the entire string: `15-APR-2012 @ 11:00:00` is shown as the match. But there are really 2 matches. How can I get both matches? I should see index 0 and index 12. The code I'm using is from another SO thread:

```
// Get a collection of matches.
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inPutString, regexptrn);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
        {
            retVal += String.Format("Index={0}, Value={1}", capture.Index, capture.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
        }
}
```

Do I have the wrong idea about what .Matches() really does?

---

OK. this is a follow up same string, new regex "(..)(...)" replacing with [$1]{$2} results in 
[10]{-AU}[G-]{201}[2 ]{@ 1}[1:]{45:}38 we expect this.

Matches however gives this:

```
Index=0, Value=10-AU
Index=5, Value=G-201 
Index=10, Value=2 @ 1 
Index=15, Value=1:45:
```

This shows that Matches looks at the entire pattern and NOT its groups. Now how to get the group matches

Comment: Please edit your question and add this info to it.  It's impossible to read source code in comments.

Comment: Moved comment to post as requested.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons your current regular expression can never get multiple matches:

- The `^` at the beginning of your regex is an anchor to the beginning of the string, so you need to remove this otherwise you regex can only match at index 0.
- The `.*` at the end of your regex will match the remainder of the string, and you won't find any overlapping matches so you can only match once.  Since you are not doing anything with the second capture group anyway, you can probably just drop this from your regex.

...so try using the regex `(\d+\D+\d+)` and replacing matches with `[$1]`.

Comment: With regard to the regex it 'works' but the second capture is not reported. I'm only squarebracketing $1 then displaying $2. I know its capturing them, Matches() is not reporting both of them and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are confusing groups and matches. A group is something between parenthesis like this (group). A match is something that fits the entire regexp. There are of course methods for not including parts of the matched string in either one of them.

Comment: How can I get these matches? Will I have to regex the regex and run seperate calls for each group?